# Email notification to queue members not firing

Tags: email

I have a case Assignment rule set up to add cases to a queue.

I have set up the queue with members and checked the 'send notification email', but when I create a case, the case is assigned to the queue but email notification is not sent.

I made sure the deliverability in email administration is 'all emails'.

Comment: Are you in a sandbox environment?   If so, the email alerts are disabled except for system messages, so none of your notifications would be sent/received until you re-enable this option.

Answer (score 2):

When you add an entry to your case assignment rules, there is a field that says "Email Template", if that field remains empty, the members of the queue will not receive any notification, you must choose an email template.

P.S. Sorry for my writing in English, it's not my native language

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the checkbox in queue "Send Email to Members" as well as the checkbox in assignment rule "Email", by selecting an Email Template in your assignment rule.

Comment: May be I am missing something. I found a link please cross check your settings with this link : https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=setting_up_queues.htm&siteLang=en_US

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me also. I was setting up the Lead assignment rule.
and queue is set-up and send email to members check box is checked but no emails were triggered but when I added "Email template" in lead rules & Email check box is checked for that rule and then I started receiving email.
Hope this helps to you also.

So this means that if we add **Email template** to assignment rule then and only then Email alerts goes.

Comment: and my Queue Email is set to blank on Queue

Answer (score 0):

Few cases which I encounter that you should use a valid email address in the environment if the emails address are not valid for that user then they never receives an email.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 3 things to trigger queue notifications:

1. Check the Send Email to Members checkbox on the Queue record page
2. Add the email template to the Lead or Case assignment rule
3. Create an email alert with the email template for the object that the queue is related to and add all recipients for email alert

Number 3 is often missed and thus the email is not sent

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Setup,
search for Process Automation Setting
Then You need to check the checkbox Under
Send an email notification
Now you will be able to Sent the email notification to the user while assigning a case to the Queue